# Custom TreeView OnDrawNode is never called

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

I have created a custom tree view control in .NET to display directories.

What I want is for the nodes to display the folder name and also the date last modified.

I can do this by just setting the text to include this but then when I try and get child nodes using full path it also includes the date and so the folder is not found.

So I tried overriding OnDrawNode to display the date as it is stored in the tag property of the node. However when I run the app it is never called.

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawAll` or `OwnerDrawText`. Otherwise, the nodes are drawn by the system, and `OnDrawNode` is not called

---

UPDATE : to combine the default rendering with your custom rendering, you can do that :

```
    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
        base.OnDrawNode(e);
        // your custom rendering here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to draw the default but just also append some text to the node? It's a lot of work to get it looking like the default. Maybe it would be best changing the code so that I replace the date with blank before searching using full path?

Comment: Doh, how did I miss that :( Thanks, I'll try it later.